# Pass Variable To Another file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, buttonclick

I got two files(A.html,B.php). A.html has some buttons. When a button is clicked,I want to pass a variable with the button id to B.php. How I can do that?

Comment: using an ajax call

Comment: Or send it in the querystring, or save it in localstorage, or sessionstorage, or a cookie...

Comment: You don't necessarily "pass a variable to a file", but you can certainly include values in a variety of operations.  The question is, what is your operation?  What are you doing?  Are you posting a form?  Clicking a link?  Should the user navigate to this new page?  Something else?  A more complete (but still minimal) example of what you're trying to do would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 files should be on the same location and php is installed in your server

**A.html**

```html
...
<a href="B.php?data1=1654&data2=string">Button</a>
...
```

**B.php**

```
<?php

echo $_GET['data1']; // output "1654"
echo $_GET['data2']; // output "string"
```